# Changing Developer Tools Font Face (family)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

After hours of research, I give up.

Is there any straightforward way to hack Dev Tools and change the font family they are using? I'm spending many hours looking at this window so I'd love if I could use a monospaced font of my choice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This one I learnt from [Darcy Clarke](https://www.darcyclarke.me/articles/development/skin-your-chrome-inspector/), and I got to his post by following a link by Paul Irish or Addy Osmany. I never thought there will come the day in which someone would ask for that very precise feature.

**a) You need to enable devtools experimental features (open `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments` in your url field). Restart Chrome.**

[image]

**b)  Open devtools settings, and in the experiments tab, enable UI theming**

[image]

**3.- Browse for [devtools themes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/devtools%20theme) among chrome extensions or use [Paul Irish's sample](https://github.com/paulirish/sample-devtools-theme-extension) theme to build your own.**

Enjoy!

Comment: Did anyone have it working with @font-face ?

I'm trying to load the fonts using the urls in use for the custom images of themes, like

src: url(chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf)  format('opentype');

Comment: Seems this experiments flag no longer works, so most of these answers are dead in the water.

Comment: I don't want to install third party plugins when I don't know if I can trust them.

Comment: Is there anything similar for MS Edge? I've change the default font-family but the dev tools still showing in consolas. Any ideas?

Answer (score 34):

I've created a small plugin which provides a collection of editor settings for Chrome Developer Tools, **including the ability to set a custom font family enabled on your computer**.

1. Install [DevTools Author Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-author/egfhcfdfnajldliefpdoaojgahefjhhi) from Chrome Web Store
2. Enable Developer Tools experiments in chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments. Restart Chrome for
   flags to take effect.
3. Open DevTools (cmd + opt + I); Settings > Experiments > check Allow custom UI themes.

This will add an 'Author Settings' panel to Chrome Developer Tools, where you can edit the font-family being applied to the Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

Comment: it stopped working late last year (i.e. it doesn't work in the more recent versions of Chrome)...

Comment: STOPPED WORKING :(

Answer (score 6):

1. Enable devtools experimental features
2. Open devtools settings, and in the experiments tab, enable UI theming
3. Download [DevTools Font Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-font-changer/fikbcnlbgoafooldbkgikejejhaddajg) from chrome web store
4. Open devtools settings, and in the Devtools Font Changer, Change the font in Font-Family input field

Comment: As noted in other comments, the whole flag in Chrome is now gone, so none of these solutions work anymore.

Comment: @jerclarke DevTools Font Changer extension is working just fine.

Comment: Ok the self-description of the extension still tells you to use a flag that no longer exists, that's why I wrote the comment. If you are managing to get the extension to work anyway, I'll give it a shot with the updated instructions above.

Comment: Look at that, it can work! Got my Jetbrains Mono in the editor, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Worked for me too. Now I have https://Recursive.design everywhere!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use devtools experiments if you only want ton customize devtools font.
Just go in settings and change fixed-width font : `chrome://settings/fonts?search=font`

Comment: Didn't work for me - only the "DevTools Font Changer" extension + "Allow custom UI themes"

Comment: Same for me. It doesn't seem to have any effect (despite finding that setting and altering it), but following the specific instructions in Zeeshan's answer above did work.

Comment: Good idea, but that setting doesn't effect Developer Tools, only view source.